# Golang in OS X 10.9 : CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm ERROR

Tags: macos, go

```
cd /usr/local/go/src
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm ./make.bash

# Building C bootstrap tool.
cmd/dist

# Building compilers and Go bootstrap tool for host, darwin/amd64.
lib9
libbio
libmach
misc/pprof
cmd/addr2line
cmd/cov
cmd/nm
cmd/objdump
cmd/pack
cmd/prof
cmd/cc
cmd/gc
cmd/6l
cmd/5l
/usr/local/go/src/cmd/5l/../ld/lib.c:661:9: error: no case matching constant switch condition '53'
[-Werror]
switch(thechar){
.......^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
go tool dist: FAILED: gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-missing-braces -Wno-parentheses -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-switch -Wno-comment -Werror -fno-common -ggdb -pipe -O2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -c -m64 -I /usr/local/go/include -I /usr/local/go/src/cmd/5l -o /usr/local/go/pkg/obj/cmd/5l/lib.o /usr/local/go/src/cmd/5l/../ld/lib.c
```

`CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=<b>amd64</b> ./make.bash` is normal!
Only the **"arm"** is not normal.

**#/usr/local/go/src/cmd/ld/lib.c code:**

```
vi cmd/ld/lib.c
661 switch(thechar){
662 case '8':
663 argv[argc++] = "-m32";
664 break;
665 case '6':
666 argv[argc++] = "-m64";
667 break;
668 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm really not sure about anything in OSX, but perhaps the command should read

```
export CGO_ENABLED=0 ; export GOOS=linux ; export GOARCH=arm ; ./make.bash
```

instead?